# Which URL variations to add in to Analytics and Search Console?

Tags: apache, url, redirect, analytics, lets-encrypt

I have a domain example.co.uk on an Apache web server that is secured with a letsencrypt ssl certificate. Currently it redirects all http requests to https. I have also setup redirects from non-www to www, meaning all traffic ends up at https://www.example.co.uk

So I have four variations of the URL that always end up at this location:

http://example.co.uk
http**s**://example.co.uk
http://**www**.example.co.uk
http**s**://**www**.example.co.uk

I am trying to set up Google Search Console and Analytics. My question is which URLs do I need to add in to the two? Currently I have all four variations set up in Search Console with a sitemap attached to them all, or do I only need to do this for one? I have told the https www URL to prefer www in search results, which changes it for all four variations.

In Analytics should I only add https://www.example.co.uk as this is where all the traffic ends up, or do I need to add all variations of the URL to see all the traffic?

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer: no, unless you are migrating an existing site to https for the first time.

If all requests for your site eventually redirect to https://www.example.co.uk via a permanent 301 status code, then there isn't any benefit to adding all the links in Google Search Console. This feature is useful if you have duplicate content, such as an `http` site that you can't redirect to your `https` version for some reason, or if you've just migrated your site to a different domain name or URL scheme. If you're migrating an existing site to `https`, you can track how many `http` pages are still indexed while watching your `https` pages get indexed separately.

Otherwise, if you add all four links, you'll only see pages on the https://www.example.co.uk site get indexed. The Search Console allows you to track your site in the Google index, and if you are using 301 redirects then Google should never index the non-http versions of your site.